# Having issues with making my first webproject with Maven and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I am aving a issues with making my first webproject with Maven and Eclipse...

I am new to using maven and I am trying to learn it. I been using Eclipse and Coding Web and Spring projects for a long time but never using maven so I want to learn it.

I Create new maven project using archetype: maven-archetype-webapp from within eclipse then I make change to my POM.XML to have the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springsource.greenbeans.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebFlowTemplate</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WebFlowTemplate Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>WebFlowTemplate</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

and then I made a small index.jsp to test:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="login.jsp">Login</a><p><p>
    <a href="hello.html">Say Hello (Spring MVC)</a><p>
    <a href="./helloworld">Say Hello (Spring-Web-Flow)</a>
</body>
</html>
```

but I am getting errors on the taglib line:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

```
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" input.jsp   /WebFlowTemplate/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/helloworld   line 1  JSP Problem
```

why can't the JSP find the taglibs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URI for jstl should be something like:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>
```

See the discussion [here](http://www.mularien.com/blog/2008/04/24/how-to-reference-and-use-jstl-in-your-web-application/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the servlet api as dependency and mark it as provided. Or look for the maven taglib dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```